# Example for GrowlNotification and Callback on Mac

Tags: callback, applescript, growl, growlnotify

I am new to Growl notifications. My chat application shows some growl messages whenever a message is received. When the user clicks on the growl message, I should be able to popup the application window with the message on the window.

Is there an example or tutorial for Growl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like the [Implementing Growl support in your Cocoa Application](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/implementing-growl.php) page from the official Growl docs?

Or, since you mention AppleScript, perhaps you were looking for [Sample AppleScript Notification](http://growl.info/documentation/applescript-support.php#simpleNotificationSampleCode), also from their docs.